# angular http get send body params as json in request

Tags: angular, httpclient

i' m trying to make this request in angular:

```
curl --location --request GET 'http://localhost:5000/location/searchDistanceAndTags?pageNo=1&size=1' \
--header 'token: $IKFASOmV#*+JIL4X0FGTDZNRPB3GN7HvAB9QD2X8QWeLsqtKW1U5YHnxCMRywEbUZlu??oz!!!!6r' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
"lat": "38.8993487",
"lng": "-77.0145665",
"radius": "100",
"tags": ["bier"]
}'
```

here is my code in angular, unfortunately the params are not set (backend doesnt receive any data in req.body)

```
 const dataset = {
  lat: '38.8993487',
  lng: '-77.0145665',
  radius: '100',
  tags: ['bier']
};

return this._httpClient.get<any>(`http://localhost:5000/location/searchDistanceAndTags?pageNo=${this.pageNumber}&size=10`, {
  headers: {token: this.apikey,
    'Content-Type':  'application/json'},
  params: dataset
});
```

Comment: this is get method . what do u mean from body ? you can't send from body with get method

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Even though GET request can technically have a body like indicated in this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/983458/1160794), not many libraries actually support it. CURL does, as you've indicated. However, front end APIs like fetch, Xhr (XmlHttpRequest) will not allow to send a body in a GET request.

Angular's `HttpClient` uses Xhr if I'm not mistaken, and so you won't be allowed to do this.

You can either modify your API to accept a post request instead, or accept the parameters in the query string

Answer (score 0):

Params can be sent via HttpParams:

```
const params = new HttpParams()
   .set('lat', 'one!')
   .set('lng', "two");  // and so on
```

headers can be created via:

```
const headers = new HttpHeaders()
        .set("X-CustomHeader", "custom header value");
```

and

```
this.httpClient.get<any>(yoururl,{params}) // {params} short form of {params:params}
or:
this.httpClient.get<any>(yoururl,{headers: headers, params: params})
```

Comment: If you uses GET, the params will be send by queryParam, not as body params.